# How can one obtain the list of news articles, blog posts and other online content that mention a given patent or patent application?

Tags: uspto, search

E.g., I see that this [news article](https://www.thedailyupside.com/technology/artificial-intelligence/adobes-multimodal-model-could-make-ai-summaries-clearer/) mentioned [this patent application](https://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2024/0020337.html). How can one obtain the list of news articles, blog posts and other online content that mention a given patent or patent application? I am mostly interested in USPTO patents and patent applications.

Comment: The linked article references the patent number only in a link and I have seen many articles that reference a patent without any mention of the number or even the complete title - you want to find all of these?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite the more exhaustive the list is, the better, but I understand that the solution won't be perfect

Comment: A google search?

Comment: @EricS I was hoping for a more advanced solution, if it exists.

Comment: I don’t know of one although Google Scholar sometimes finds useful stuff.